# Visual effects, and Activity redraw after pressing home button and come back

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

I am programming an Android app and it seems to work well, but when the user presses the 'home' button, and after returns to the app, the activity has changed his position some pixels, and due to this some buttons are hidden.

It only happens in some phone models , and only with visual effects enabled on the operating system.

It seems that the activity is drawn before the top bar of Android dissapears (the bar with the battery info, wifi... etc), and the activity starts to draw under the place of this bar.

What can be happening? how can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

PD: I am using a relative layout on this activity, and some layouts inside placed at top and bottom.

PD2: I forgot to tell that the app is in "no tittle bar and fullscreen".